# Execute systemctl hibernate without password challenge

Tags: 18.04, password, hibernate

How to configure Ubuntu 18.04 when executing `systemctl hibernate` password challenge is not required.

```
$ id -a
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(coka),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
```

Please attached image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add the proper entry to sudo:

```
username        ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl hibernate
```

Comment: Try above. Didn't work.

Comment: `sudo systemctl hibernate` didn't work? I wanted something similar (for suspend), so I made an alias: `alias quit='sudo systemctl suspend'`.

Comment: In my case, the reason it did not work was that the tutorial I followed to enable hibernation used `pkexec systemctl hibernate` in the keyboard shortcut. After replacing `pkexec` by `sudo` it worked flawlessly!