# How to hibernate from Gnome Shell Extension without password?

Tags: sudo, gnome-shell, hibernate

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04) I have installed [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/) Gnome Shell Extension that modifies the style of the power-off options and also adds an option to hibernate, which I occasionally use on my system in place of suspend. While the extension works as expected, every time I want to hibernate, I am prompted for a superuser password in order to proceed, which is annoying. To get rid of the password dialog, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166207) answer and added

```
my_username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl hibernate
```

to my sudoers. After this change, I am able to hibernate from command line without password, as expected. However, the corresponding option from said Gnome Shell Extension still prompts me for a password. The code behind the scenes of the extension can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/K3rcus/simpler-off-menu/-/blob/master/extension.js#L62). I was unable to find any implementation of the function `Util.trySpawnCommandLine`, but it appears that it would just call the supplemented command in a shell. Hence, it's not clear to me, why I am still asked for a password. I have checked that `which systemctl` returns `/bin/systemctl`. Could it be that commands from the Gnome Shell are executed in a different user context than the logged in user?

PS: Is it considered safe from a security standpoint, anyway, to add above line to the sudoers file?

Comment: There is a extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/ this does not require root password. If you want to stick with the extension you mentioned.. tweaking that extension can do the job. I suggest you to try that extension, if that works, I can help to integrate the same to your installed extension.

Comment: For me the extension, which you suggest, does not work. In Ubuntu 20.04, at least for me, there are no longer those circular buttons to power off. When installing the extension, nothing happens in the menu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1260588/739431

Comment: For me the extension does not work, too. And hitting `ALT+F2` and giving the `systemctl hibernate` command does not require any password by default. Did you install the extension system wide, or for user only?

Comment: Oh, that was way too fast I guess. The extension does its trick for me without giving a password prompt.

Comment: @ranguwud "I am able to hibernate from command line without password, as expected." what is the command you are using `sudo systemctl hibernate` or `systemctl hibernate`. if the first one not asking password then you need to edit the extension.js file `Util.trySpawnCommandLine`. I have tested this in Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked. However my in my system `which systemctl` returns `/usr/bin/systemctl`

Comment: ALT+ F2 is a TTY. By default they run as login shells. The username pwd is the point in that case.

Comment: When you do something via an application, from the OS's perspective, it usually looks like the application is trying to execute the command. Therefore, the application, not your user acct. needs the proper group/ permissions.Apps have groups too. try adding the app's group to `sudoers`.